# Custom DNS for Specific Access Points in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns, firewall, google-public-dns

I would like to use Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4) at home, but the school firewall works through DNS, so using a custom name server disables accessing the internet.

Is there any way to automatically use Google DNS at home, but switch to auto-configure when at school?

It's annoying to have to switch it between home and school. I do this because I notice significant speed increases versus the Comcast DNS. I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium x64, and I'd have no issue with installing third-party software or scripts in order to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes access to the router is not an option. Check out [**NetSetMan**](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm). It lets you define settings per network.

[image]

Also, here is the link to [the blog about this tool](http://www.techmixer.com/free-network-ip-profile-managers-list/) and other similar ones, which got me to try the application in the first place.

Comment: Downloading as we speak :)

Comment: Although not open-source, it works perfectly. I already found an alternate solution (Setting Google's DNS in my router config) but I'm sure it will come in handy in the future.